# Namespace and function name collision

Tags: php, namespaces

I have declared a method for my class called `list()`, and to avoid its colliosn/error with PHP's own `list()` function, put it in a namespace. But unfortunately I still get the error. Her is scenario:

I have declared a namespace at the top of my file:

```
<?php namespace MyNameSpace\ThisClass;
use MyNameSpace\ThisClass;
```

And then the class:

```
Class AClass 
{
  function list()
{
// something here
}
}
```

And then instanciate it.

```
$x = MyNameSpace\ThisClass\AClass();
```

I have declared the class in a namespace and expecting it to ignore `list()` method collision with PHP's own `list()` function. However, php throws following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'list' (T_LIST), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

Why I still get the error considering the fact that my list() function is nested in a namespace?

Comment: How you are calling the `$class->list();` method? Also show us your `list()` method definition.

Comment: It doesn't matter, I have commented out instanciation, the PHP throws PHP while class is declared.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As from [PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php):

> These words have special meaning in PHP. Some of them represent things
> which look like functions, some look like constants, and so on - but
> they're not, really: they are **language constructs**. You cannot use any
> of the following words as **constants**, **class** names, **function** or **method**
> names. Using them as variable names is generally OK, but could lead to
> confusion.

Reserved words like:

- `list()`
- `die()`
- `include_once()`

Comment: +1 That is why I made a script that would find any reserved words and replace them accordingly.